# Streaming excel sheet using REST

Tags: apache-poi

I have a new requirement to download a excel sheet using REST API.(Export All Data). We are using an in-house UI framework which will help us to use a REST API and it will be from the browser. Since I am dealing with huge amount of data, the approach we were thinking was like this,

1. Create SXSSFWorkbook

`final SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); 
        Sheet sh = wb.createSheet();`

2. Use batching to get the data from DB and creating the rows in excel sheet. (In a while loop we are issuing db query to get the list of rows. Then from the list, we are creating the rows in excel sheet- code below shows how I am creating the rows and columns in excel using the results)

`for ( List<Object> rowResults : allResultsData ) {
                row = sh.createRow(rowIndex++);
                cellIndex = 0;
                for ( Object columnData : rowResults ) {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex++);
                    cell.setCellValue(columnData != null ? columnData.toString() : null);
                }
            }`

3. Return type of the method is StreamingOutput. The workbook is written to StreamingOutput's OutputStream

`return new StreamingOutput() {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                try {
                    LOGGER.info("============= Going to start Streaming ============");
                    wb.write(output);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new WebApplicationException(e);
                } finally {
                    wb.dispose();
                }
            }
        };`

The above approach works for small amount of data. I noticed that the Streaming starts ONLY AFTER the whole excel file is created. So when it's huge amount of data, then Streaming does NOT START until the whole excel is created (which takes some time) and we are seeing ERROR in browser.

I would like to know whether I am using the API correctly. Also if these libraries are not for this purpose, then can anybody suggests any other solutions? Is there any library we can use so that we can START streaming from partially created excel sheet.

Thanks in advance,

SD